# I would like to know whether label column accepts such sub zero values or empty values

Tags: sorting, integer, label, gooddata

I would like to apply natural number sort order to the attribute representing members' age, but including sub zero values and empty values in addition to the natural human age.
I would like to know whether label column accepts such sub zero values or empty values inevitably flown into from the manually input source data like logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!
You have to change the data type of the label from Varchar(128) to Integer.

There are two ways to do it:

1. run MAQL: "ALTER DATATYPE {f_dataset_name.nm_label_name} INT;"
2. Go to CloudConnect LDM modeler. Click on Dataset => Edit => Show
   DataTypes => change datatype on label to Integer

This data type accepts also sub zero values. For "null" or "empty" values there has to be upper case null string "NULL" in the source data.

Comment: I would like to know whether there is any other way like setIntValue function than input data in initializing integer property as NULL in CloudConnect reformat component.

Comment: there is one option in CloudConnect metadata settings. The field has to be: default="NULL" nullable="false" type="string"